# Parameter array versus IEnumerabl​e<T> for an API

Tags: c#

I have an C# API that can take 0/1/Many paramters of same type. What should be better way to have a API defined = `params` versus `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific than this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would almost always use `params` for APIs like that, since it allows the caller to pass the arguments without having to manually construct a container for them.

This:

```
SomeMethod(param1, param2, param3);
```

is just cleaner than requiring this:

```
SomeMethod(new[] { param1, param2, param3 });
```

However, if you are specifically operating on a *single sequence* of items, then `IEnumerable<T>` is more sensible. As well, if you expect > 5 or so parameters, then an enumerable makes more sense, since at that point the calling method starts to look pretty bad.

It really comes down to the logical operation of the API, along with the number of parameters you are actually expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `params` array when the number of parameters is small but undefined.

Use an `IEnumerable` when the number of parameters is large, or is a set of same objects, as in customers or orders.